# Remove messages from an included CMakeList.txt

Tags: cmake

I'm including a project into mine by using a simple `add_subdirectory`.

However, that project is quite verbose and fill my build with many messages.
Without modifying the external project... is it possible to remove all (or part) of those annoying imported messages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the external project itself does not support it (like e.g. [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105020/cmake-module-that-improves-upon-checklibrariesexists)), you still have the option to overwrite the `message()` function and declare your own algorithm/check when to print messages.

Here is a version with a simple check for a variable named `MESSAGE_QUIET`:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(MessageQuiet)

function(message)
    if (NOT MESSAGE_QUIET)
        _message(${ARGN})
    endif()
endfunction()

set(MESSAGE_QUIET ON)
add_subdirectory(ExternalProject)
unset(MESSAGE_QUIET)

message(STATUS "Hello from my project")
```

**ExternalProject\CMakeLists.txt**

```
message("Hello from external project")
```

Comment: What is `_message`?

Comment: @Dadam Sorry, forgot to explain that part. When you want to call the original function in a overwritten version you just need to add an underscore `_` as a prefix.

Answer (score 1):

By including a subdirectory, you cannot suppress the output.

If it is a find script, you can call it with `QUIET`. If you can call the script with `cmake -P scriptToExecute` instead of including the sub-directory, you can redirect the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adjusting the [CMAKE_MESSAGE_LOG_LEVEL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MESSAGE_LOG_LEVEL.html) variable:

```
set(_saved_CMAKE_MESSAGE_LOG_LEVEL ${CMAKE_MESSAGE_LOG_LEVEL})
set(CMAKE_MESSAGE_LOG_LEVEL NOTICE)
add_subdirectory(ExternalProject)
set(CMAKE_MESSAGE_LOG_LEVEL ${_saved_CMAKE_MESSAGE_LOG_LEVEL})
```